# Difference between iterators, enumerations and sequences

Tags: ocaml

I want to understand what is the difference between iterators, enumerations and sequences in ocaml

```
enumeration:
type 'a t = {
  mutable count : unit -> int; (** Return the number of remaining elements       in the enumeration. *)
  mutable next  : unit -> 'a;  (** Return the next element of the   enumeration or raise [No_more_elements].*)
  mutable clone : unit -> 'a t;(** Return a copy of the enumeration. *)
  mutable fast  : bool;        (** [true] if [count] can be done without reading all elements, [false] otherwise.*)
}
sequence:

type 'a node =
| Nil
| Cons of 'a * 'a t
and 'a t = unit -> 'a node
```

I don't have any idea about iterators

Answer (score 13):

### Enumerations/Generators

[`BatEnum`](https://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatEnum.html) (what you call "enumeration", but let's use module names instead) is more or less isomorphic to a generator, which is often said *pull-based*:

```
generator : unit -> 'a option
```

This means "Each time you call `generator ()`, I will give you a new element from the collection, until there are no more elements and it returns `None`". Note that this means previous elements are not accessible. This behavior is called "destructive".
This is similar to the [gen](https://github.com/c-cube/gen/) library. Such iterators are fundamentally very imperative (they work by maintaining a current state).

### Sequences

Pull-based approaches are not necessarily destructive, this is where the [`Seq`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/seq.mli) type fits. It's a list-like structure, except each node is hidden behind a closure. It's similar to lazy lists, but without the guaranty of persistency. You can manipulate these sequences pretty much like lists, by pattern matching on them.

```
type 'a node =
| Nil
| Cons of 'a * 'a seq
and 'a seq = unit -> 'a node
```

### Iterators

Iterators such as [sequence](https://github.com/c-cube/sequence/blob/master/src/Sequence.mli), also said "push-based", have a type that is similar to the `iter` function that you find on many data-structures:

```
iterator : ('a -> unit) -> unit
```

which means "`iterator f` will apply the `f` function to all the elements in the collection`.

### What's the difference?

One key difference between pull-based and push-based approaches is their expressivity. Consider that you have two generators, `gen1` and `gen2`, it's easy to add them:

```
let add gen1 gen2 =
  let gen () = 
    match gen1(), gen2() with
    | Some v1, Some v2 -> Some (v1+v2)
    | _ -> None
  in
  gen
```

However, you can't really write such a function with most push-based approaches such as `sequence`, since you don't completely control the iteration.

On the flip side, push-based iterators are usually easier to define and are faster.

### Recommendation

Starting in OCaml 4.07, [`Seq`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/seq.mli) is available in the standard library. There is a [`seq`](https://github.com/c-cube/seq/) compatibiliy package that you can use right now, and a large library of combinators in the associated [oseq](https://github.com/c-cube/oseq/) library.
`Seq` is fast, expressive and fairly easy to use, so I recommend using it.

Comment: *but without the guaranty of persistency* I don't understand why. 

And if I understand it, it means that an iterator is a sequence which waits a function to do something? And do you have any documentation explaining the difference between push-based and pull-based?

Comment: Let's say you return a sequence of all the primes. Each time you access a cons, it will compute the next prime (through a cribble, for example). If you do it with a lazylist, the result is memoized and the next access will not require any computation. With a thunklist, this is not the case by default. Memoization would be explicit.

Comment: So push means you already have the result and just returns it and pull means you have to compute it every time?

Comment: No, that's unreleated. Push vs. Pull is the thing that I highlighted in the paragraph "What's the difference". In one approach you control the iteration and you "pull" the value when you want. In the other you don't control the iteration and the value is "pushed" on you.

Comment: Oh, OK, that's why I didn't understand how it was related. :-D

Comment: But why having an explicit memoization or not guarantees the persistency?

Comment: Most iterators are use transiently and Seq is faster than LazyList in practice.

Comment: Is this an answer to the persistence problem?

Answer (score 0):

An enumeration is not what you wrote, you just defined a record here. An enumeration is a type that contains multiple constructors but a variable can only pick one value at a time in it (you can see it as the union type in C) :

```
type enum = One | Two | Three

let e = One
```

A sequence is, as you write it, simply a recursive enumeration type (in your case you defined what is usually called *a list*).

To simplify, let's call the special structures that contains some elements of the same type a `container` (some known `containers` are `arrays`, `lists`, `sets`, `maps` etc)

An iterator is a function that applies the same function to each elements of a `container`. So you would have the `map` iterator which applies a function to each element but keep the structure as it is (for example, adding 1 to each element of a list l : `List.map (fun e -> e + 1) l`). The `fold` operator which applies a function to each element and an accumulator and returns the accumulator (for example, adding each element of a list l and returning the result : `List.fold_left (fun acc e -> acc + e) l`).

So,

- enumeration and sequence : structures
- iterators : function over each element of the structures

Comment: You seem to be missing a chunk of the context. What he's really asking is the difference between "enumeration" in the style of [BatEnum](https://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatEnum.html), structures such as [Seq](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/seq.mli) ([Oseq](https://c-cube.github.io/oseq/oseq/OSeq/index.html), [BatSeq](https://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatSeq.html)), which by the way are *not* lists, and Iterators (such as [Sequence](https://github.com/c-cube/sequence/blob/master/src/Sequence.mli)).

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed (but I think he's a she ;-)). But in my answer I'm wrong about enumeration and the fact that the sequence is not a list but a lazy list, no?

Comment: It's not exactly a lazy list either (I tend to call them "thunk lists"). Lazy lists are persistent, `Seq.t` might not be.

Comment: "she" ;) yes i meant BatSeq, baEnum and iterators in these sens

Comment: I found that sequences are mutable and Enum are not, i didn't really get why !! and still don't have an idea about iterators

Comment: Sorry! Your question is a bit more delicate to answer that one would expect because `BatEnum` is a very complicated over-engineered mess, so defining what it is isn't completely straightforward. I will try to give a complete answer later, but the short version is: From now on, Use `Seq` (through either the next version of ocaml's standard library or the `oseq` package) and avoid using `BatEnum`.